# scroll a div to the left/right using jQuery Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am having certain issues with animatedly scrolling a `div` from the left to the right and right to left.In this [Fiddle for what I have tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/rdUws/) , there are 9 small icon placeholders on the top.In the main container , there are appropriate large sized placeholders to each of those icons.Suppose I click on the last icon , the large placeholder container scrolls to the appropriate last placeholder.

The issue which I am facing is that , if I click the second icon,my large placeholder container animates by one placeholder to the left,which is correct.After this if I click on the fourth icon , my large placeholder container still animates by one placeholder to the left,which is incorrect.It should move 2 placeholders.I see the same issue with scrolling to the right as well.

Can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve a slideshow like this? http://tutorialzine.com/2009/11/beautiful-apple-gallery-slideshow/

Comment: no worries, this is an excellent tutorial that I followed to create slideshows. If you have any questions, just post here and I should get a notification. I have made several slideshows at this point